# multiple by elementID scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
       document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
      var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
      e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
    });
    document.getElementById('phone-mobile-main').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
      var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
      e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
    });
document.getElementById('phone-mobile-main').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
      var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
      e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
    });
```

Ok, so I have these three blocks of JS, they each do the same thing, the reason I have them is on my page, I have 3 forms, one for mobile, one for a modal popup, and one that slides along the right side. All have the same form. So what I was wondering is, is there a way to just do one block, and when a user selects it, it uses just one block of this code, instead of having to post it multiple times. I hope how I'm explaining this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#phone, #phone-mobile-main');
if(elements.length > 0) {
  elements.forEach(function(element){
      element.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
          var x = element.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
          element.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
      });
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="phone" type="text">
<input id="phone-mobile-main" type="text">
```

Which will cover the code you showed from above.

The question is: Why do you have different IDs for mobile and non-mobile. That does not really make sense. You should consider how you can change your markup (HTML) as it should be the same for mobile and desktop. Javascript and CSS is just a layer on that.

> Ok, so I have these three blocks of JS, they each do the same thing,
>   the reason I have them is on my page, I have 3 forms

Also note, IDs should be unique. Means on the entire page every ID can only be there once. Also if it's in a modal window. (An exception would be if they are in a iframe, which is handled again as one page). You only had 2 different ids but said you have 3.

Do the same thing with another selector

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-phone="true"]');
if(elements.length > 0) {
  elements.forEach(function(element){
      element.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
          var x = element.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
          element.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
      });
  });
}
```

```html
<input data-phone="true" type="text">
<input data-phone="true" type="text">
```

Read more about [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) where you could select elements with classes like `document.querySelectorAll('.myClass')`

Comment: I have different ID's for all, bc that block wouldn't work for one, but my question would be, could i make the JS trigger a class, so I didn't have to have unique ID's for each, then I could drive the form out of one include page. Also, if the #phone ID or whatever isn't present, it haults JS, is there a way to to skip it if it doesn't have it.

Comment: Also, your script:
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).addEventListener is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (common-func.js:466)
    at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)

Comment: Like what if I did it as a function on click, run that script, JS is difficult for me for some reason, never understood why, I can program php fine with no problems, but JS just never clicked.

Comment: Got it:

function phoneverify() {
    this.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
});
}

Comment: Nevermind, now when i select it, it select's all inputs instead of the one with onfocus=phoneverify(), how do I get it to just do it for that specific input without having to reference it as an ID since there are multiple of the same on the page.